# Could this insert statement insert duplicates?

Tags: sql-server-2008, duplicates

```
insert items (ean)
select ean
from books
where ean not in (select ean from mrs..items)
```

Assume there are duplicates in books.  Will sql determine which records to insert upfront and then continue to insert duplicates; or will it prevent itself from inserting duplicates by checking as it goes along?

Comment: Do you wish to insert duplicate's as well?

Comment: No.  And I oversimplified the query... there are more fields and some of them could vary (or rather shouldn't vary, but do) so using distinct won't help.  I could group and use min() on those fields but I just wanted to see if this would work.

Comment: I haven't tested your query yet but just by looking at it i believe it will run.

Comment: oh and BTW it should be insert into items not insert items

Comment: @Amit Wrong on both accounts :)  I went ahead and tested it and it doesn't run, but in SQL SERVER you don't have to write 'into' (but you can if you like being verbose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
insert into items (ean) 
select Distinct ean 
from books
```

Comment: Actually I couldn't use distinct cause of other fields, but I ended up just grouping and doing max()'s on the other fields so it's pretty much the same difference.

Answer (score 1):

It would create duplicates but you could prevent that by specifying distinct on the select as seen below.

```
insert into items (ean)
select distinct ean
from books
where ean not in (select ean from mrs..items)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below

```
insert into items (ean) 
select TOP 1 WITH TIES ean 
from books 
where ean not in (select ean from mrs..items) 
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ean ORDER BY <criteria>)
```

You just need to specify criteria, how the one record from duplicates should be selected for insertion.

Answer (score 0):

What I miss in previous answers is the reason for the group by.

Yes your statements prevents duplicates but only if the are no duplicates in the select you are trying to insert. The insert is atomic and so is the check not in (...) is done only once.

Think in sets and not in records. Then you can do without the 'I've tested it and it works...' comments.